# Play Framework http response is not released until all active threads are finished

Tags: playframework, akka-http

I expect that Play server should return http response to the client instantly after returning response in the controller method. But what I see in the logs is that sometimes server waits for other threads to finalize their job before transmitting the response to the client.

This behavior is unpredictable. So if I sent 10 requests at the sime time to the server, it may return responses one by one or it may return all of them at the same time (with a huge delay).

What is the reason for this behavior? Can I configure it to force to only one type of behavior?

Comment: All responses are handled asynchronously in Play. If you see delays it seems to me that you're blocking in your Actions. You need to avoid blocking (that causes Play's fixed size Thread Pool to be hogged), see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ThreadPools#Understanding-Play-thread-pools or use a dedicated custom ThreadPool instead which better suits your workload.

Comment: Yes there is a blocking code in the actions. Actually I created those blocking code on purpose in order to test Play thread pool behavior. Most probably returning result puts my action into the top of the queue again and it waits for other actions to finish their jobs. But this is not always true. Sometimes it just directly returns to the client.